# NotSerializableException: kotlin.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE after setting minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, delegates, serializable

After setting `minifyEnabled true` in app `build.gradle` script I starded to receive this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = some.package.SomeClass)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1767)
    …
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: kotlin.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
```

Crash occurred when I try to pass `class SomeClass : Parcelable` to another activity.

I tried to whitelist all app classes with `-keep class some.package.**.* { *; }` but without succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue, and the current answer is wrong: adding `@delegate:Transient` on the lazy will nullify the backing field on deserialization.

Since the issue is only occuring when `minifyEnabled = true`, that's a Proguard/R8 issue. I solved it by adding the following lines to my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class * implements kotlin.Lazy {
    *;
}
```

Comment: So glad I found your answer. I encountered the exact same R8 issue and this fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm still curious on what type of optimization is messing with the deserialization process. Did any one find out yet?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy delegate use `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` object behind the scene. It's used to check if variable is declared or not. In some way [need more info] lazy delegate change their behavior during code minification. It creates situation where as long as `minifyEnabled` is disabled then passing object with lazy initialized field works fine without try to serialize it. But after enable minify Java tries to serializable `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` which throws exception in runtime.

Unfortunately stacktrace don't tell you exactly which field in which class you must update. At least it tell you which of main class contains your broken `Serializable` class.

Let's assume that in this case `some.package.SomeClass` contains `AnotherClass` field. To fix it you need to find all lazy class fields where classes implements `Serializable`. Then add `@delegate:Transient` to them, eg.

```kotlin
class AnotherClass: Serializable {

    …

    @delegate:Transient // <- add this
    val myLazyField by lazy { "Kotlin, why?!" }
}
```

Comment: That's wrong : adding `@delegate:Transient` will nullify the backing field and will throw an NPE when accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The following pro-guard settings appear to fix the problem:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```